# What's the easiest way to define an app global variable which can be used by all the classes?

Tags: objective-c, c, cocoa, global-variables

I'm making an app where I would need to set two global variables, which should be able to be modified by any class in the entire app. I tried setting on the appDelegate, on a GlobalClass class, on main.m, as a `@property` declaration, but I don't manage to get them all around the app, how could I do it? Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A really simple solution is to do something like this:

```
@interface MyClass {}
    + (NSString *)myVar;
    + (void)setMyVar:(NSString *)newVa;
@end

@implementation MyClass
    static NSString *myVar;
    + (NSString *)myVar { return myVar; }
    + (void)setMyVar:(NSString *)newVar { myVar = newVar; }
@end
```

You will then have a static variable in Objective-C ( the original blog posting about this can be found [here](http://iphonedevelopertips.com/objective-c/java-developers-guide-to-static-variables-in-objective-c.html) )